# CSS with LeafLet

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, leaflet

I use Angular 6 and Leaflet.I don't understand why can't define my css in my component... That is my code :

HTML

```
<div class="custom-popup" id="frugalmap">
```

CSS

```
.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background:#2c3e50;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:160px;
    line-height:24px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper a {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
    width:30px;
    height:15px;
}

.custom-popup .leaflet-popup-tip {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

TS

```
var customPopup = "<h4>CHU Nantes</h4>" 
var customOptions = {'className' : 'custom' }
var CHUNantes= L.marker([47.21082, -1.55446], {icon: myIcon}).bindPopup(customPopup,customOptions).on('mouseover', function (e) { this.openPopup();});
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't define your css in the component? You can using styleUrls

Comment: my css doesn't work, you see why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define custom marker as follows and **place the css on global styles.css**:

```
const myIcon = L.icon({
     // place your icon url
     iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
     iconSize: [32, 37],
     iconAnchor: [16, 37],
     popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});

const customPopup = "<h4>CHU Nantes</h4>" 
const customOptions = {'className' : 'custom-popup' }
const nantes= L.marker([47.21082, -1.55446], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);

nantes.bindPopup(customPopup,customOptions)
      .on('mouseover', function (e) { this.openPopup()});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whjgmu)